# Inserting a unique int into a non primary key field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert-into

I'm trying to make an SQL query using INSERT INTO to copy a number of rows from a table, but I want one of the fields (which isn't a primary key) to have a new, unique, int (I know this is terrible database design, but I can't change the structure of the DB).

Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
    INSERT INTO Mytable
        (field1
        ,field2
        ,field3
        ,nonKeyUniqueInt)

    SELECT
        (field1
        ,field2
        ,field3
        ,(SELECT MAX(nonKeyUniqueInt)+1 FROM mytable)
    FROM
        mytable
    WHERE
        (conditions)
```

However this doesn't work because the SELECT MAX query only runs once, giving all my new rows the same value for that field. Given the following rows to copy:

```
field1 field2 field3 nonKeyUniqueInt
x      y      z      1
a      b      c      2
```

I get output of:

```
field1 field2 field3 nonKeyUniqueInt
x      y      z      1
a      b      c      2
x      y      z      3
a      b      c      3
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: Side note: `SELECT MAX(...) + n` doesn't play nicely with concurrency, usually.  What about something like a [`SEQUENCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)?  Or do you not want to have to maintain a global object?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse You might well be right, but its basically a one off query and I wanted to do it in the simplest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the subquery gets evaluated once for the `insert`, not once per row.  The solution is to use `row_number()`:

```
INSERT INTO Mytable(field1, field2, field3, nonKeyUniqueInt)
    SELECT field1, field2, field3,
           x.maxk + row_number() over (order by (select NULL))
    FROM mytable CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT MAX(nonKeyUniqueInt) as maxk FROM mytable) x
    WHERE (conditions);
```

I moved the max calculation to the `FROM` clause to make it clear that it is evaluated only once.

Comment: I think x in your SELECT should be x.maxk

Comment: Thanks, It works perfectly in my example. However, when I tried to put it into the real database I get an error "Subquery returned more than 1 value". I can't see how it could do that! Oh well, I'm sure I'll work it out.